# ASP IDE on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide, asp-classic

What is the best free alternative to Visual Studio for ASP development on Windows platform?

Answer (score 2):

[Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

Comment: Got to love the Textpad, old skool rulez!

Answer (score 1):

Give visual studio webdeveloper expres edition a try. It has excelent code completion, even for thirdparty com objects.

Comment: Is "Visual Studio WebDeveloper Expres" i.e. http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/ free? Will it work for developing ASP classic applications?

Comment: Yes, it's free - no charge - pro bono.  You can use it for classic ASP. but it does not support Attaching to Process, so you can't use it as a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

[1st Page 2000](http://www.evrsoft.com/) understands classic ASP and includes syntax highlighting. I remember quite liking it.